# stackifickation of BG

Tags: infinity-categories, simplicial-presheaves

Let $Man$ be the category of smooth manifold. Fix a $M\in Man$ and let $G$ be a group acting smoothly on $M$. The nerve of the group action on $M$ by $G$ defines a simplicial presheaf $X\: : \:Man\to sSet$ via
$$X_{n}(N)=y(M)(N)\times G\times G \times \dots \times G,$$
where $y(-)$ is the ordinary yoneda embedding. Let $sPsh(Man)$ be the category of simplicial presheaves on $Man$ and assume that it is equipped with the projective model structure. Clearly $X$ is a fibrant objects, but it is not an (infinity) stack. Consider the model structure obtained via left Bousfield localization of $sPsh(Man)$ along the Cech covers, what is the stackification of $X$? What if $M$ is a point? Do you know some references?

EDIT: Assume that $G$ is a Lie group. Now consider the simplicial presheaf given by $Z\: : \:Man\to sSet$ via
$$Z_{n}(N)=y(M\times G\times G \times \dots \times G)(N),$$
what is its stackification? Note that if G is discrete then $Z$ is equal to $X$.

Comment: The stackification sends $N$ to the nerve of the groupoid of principal $G$-bundles over $N$ equipped with a $G$-equivariant map to $M$. It's clear that this is a stack, and I think it's what you get from $X$ by applying the plus construction just once.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Especially if you can provide a pointer to the literature, please consider upgrading your comment to an answer.

Comment: This follows from the description of the 1-stack associated to the action groupoid via right principal bibundles.

Comment: Do you know some references about the groupoid of principal $G$-bundles over a manifold?

Comment: This is probably somewhere in [Principal ∞-bundles](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0248) by Nikolaus, Schreiber, and Stevenson. Classical references either use hypercover stackification or fail to note that stackification preserves $n$-truncated presheaves, so they're not much help here.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's the same thing: the nerve of the category of principal G-bundles equipped with an equivariant map to M. Note that X is a special case of Z, as discrete groups are Lie groups.